# Bootstrap col-auto should not have more than 3 elements in a row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

`col-auto` is great. It fits items by size in a row(same line). But i want it to strictly fit not more than 3 items in a row(same line). It should only have 1-3 items in same line.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xl-4 col-xxl-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
  <div class="card border-primary mb-3 mt-2 bg-transparent text-white_disabled w-100">
    <div class="card-header bg-transparent font-weight-500">
      Languages
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <li class="col-auto text-nowrap">Rust</li>
        <li class="col-auto text-nowrap">Python</li>
        <li class="col-auto text-nowrap">PHP</li>
        <li class="col-auto text-nowrap">Java</li>
        <li class="col-auto text-nowrap">C</li>
        <li class="col-auto text-nowrap">C++</li>
        <li class="col-auto text-nowrap">Golang</li>
        <li class="col-auto text-nowrap">Kotlin</li>
        <li class="col-auto text-nowrap">Javascript</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Current Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: Please don't tag multiple Bootstrap versions. That's just confusing.

Comment: Why don't you create 3 columns then?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just be explicit about column sizes, then?

FYI, `col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xl-4 col-xxl-4` can be reduced to simply `col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4`. Read up on [Bootstrap's mobile-first philosophy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/extend/approach/).

Also, your list markup is invalid. List items must be children of list elements.

Oh, and it's just "Go". Golang is a domain name, not a language.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
  <div class="card border-primary mb-3 mt-2 bg-transparent text-white_disabled w-100">
    <div class="card-header bg-transparent font-weight-500">
      Languages
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-4 text-nowrap">Rust</li>
        <li class="col-4 text-nowrap">Python</li>
        <li class="col-4 text-nowrap">PHP</li>
        <li class="col-4 text-nowrap">Java</li>
        <li class="col-4 text-nowrap">C</li>
        <li class="col-4 text-nowrap">C++</li>
        <li class="col-4 text-nowrap">Go</li>
        <li class="col-4 text-nowrap">Kotlin</li>
        <li class="col-4 text-nowrap">Javascript</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```